# CKEditor external image path

Tags: primefaces, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, primefaces-extensions

I"m having an option to insert image inside CKEditor. For that i saved the image file in physical path inside the Server(Wildfly 10) folder and adding an `img` tag by using editor instance with (`instance.insertHTML`) option. Its working fine when the image was inside the server folder. If the image was outside the server path its not rendering in the editor as well as in the browser.

Help to store the image in external path (outside the Server path) to render the image in CKEditor as well as in the  browser.

I'm using primefaces extension for CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Your web application only has access to certain areas of the file system served from under the webapp.  This is fundamental webapp security so a user couldn't browse your server's file system for example.

Comment: But a custom servlet can help (and has q/a in stackoverflow) or something from omnifaces...